# Get the first and last value of a column of dataframe respect another column

Tags: python, dataframe, format, multiple-columns, unique-values

I'm a beginner on python and I would like to  get the first and last value of the column date always that the mac_address be the same, for example:

I've ordered my dataframe by mac_address, date with the next line:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['mac_address', 'date'], ascending=(True, True))
```

And the data are:

```
         router        mac_address      date
589455  15001391    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   2021-01-01 22:09:34
590067  17091211    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   2021-01-01 22:10:54
590136  17091236    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   2021-01-01 22:11:04
.....
.....
.....
635434  15001391    00:00:78:01:0d:11   2021-01-02 00:14:54
636479  17091211    00:00:78:01:0d:11   2021-01-02 00:16:17
949873  17091172    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:26:39
950699  17091251    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:27:59
950700  17091253    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:28:59
950702  17091257    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:29:59
950703  17091258    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:30:59
619384  17091174    00:01:09:d2:09:e0   2021-01-01 23:34:32
365351  17091211    00:01:d2:7c:4e:32   2021-01-01 14:27:58
109858  17091236    00:02:75:86:4e:34   2021-01-01 05:50:47
110281  17091211    00:02:75:86:4e:34   2021-01-01 05:50:54
```

NOTE: the date column has the format "2021-01-01 05:50:54" and the differents mac address that appears are variable in the number of times

And I would like to have two outputs like this:

first output:

```
    589455  15001391    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   2021-01-01 22:09:34
    590136  17091236    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   2021-01-01 22:11:04
    635434  15001391    00:00:78:01:0d:11   2021-01-02 00:14:54
    636479  17091211    00:00:78:01:0d:11   2021-01-02 00:16:17
    .....
    .....
    949873  17091172    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:26:39
    950703  17091258    00:00:af:82:56:93   2021-01-02 11:30:59
    619384  17091174    00:01:09:d2:09:e0   2021-01-01 23:34:32
    365351  17091211    00:01:d2:7c:4e:32   2021-01-01 14:27:58
```

second output: Just considered the data that have a first and the last value, and not be considered the mac_adress that only once appears

```
    589455  15001391    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   22:09:34
    590136  17091236    00:00:34:1a:03:e8   22:11:04
    635434  15001391    00:00:78:01:0d:11   00:14:54
    636479  17091211    00:00:78:01:0d:11   00:16:17
    .....
    .....
    949873  17091172    00:00:af:82:56:93   11:26:39
    950703  17091258    00:00:af:82:56:93   11:30:59
```

I don't know if I'm complicating or this task is easier than I see, but I've passed the last 48 hours without any favorable result. Can you help me please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data are already sorted by mac address and dates, you don't need to use `groupby`.

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['mac_address'].ne(df['mac_address'].shift())) | 
             (df['mac_address'].ne(df['mac_address'].shift(-1)))]
```

First output:

```
>>> df1
          router        mac_address                 date
589455  15001391  00:00:34:1a:03:e8  2021-01-01 22:09:34
590136  17091236  00:00:34:1a:03:e8  2021-01-01 22:11:04
635434  15001391  00:00:78:01:0d:11  2021-01-02 00:14:54
636479  17091211  00:00:78:01:0d:11  2021-01-02 00:16:17
949873  17091172  00:00:af:82:56:93  2021-01-02 11:26:39
950703  17091258  00:00:af:82:56:93  2021-01-02 11:30:59
619384  17091174  00:01:09:d2:09:e0  2021-01-01 23:34:32
365351  17091211  00:01:d2:7c:4e:32  2021-01-01 14:27:58
109858  17091236  00:02:75:86:4e:34  2021-01-01 05:50:47
110281  17091211  00:02:75:86:4e:34  2021-01-01 05:50:54
```

Second output:

```
>>> df1.loc[df1.duplicated('mac_address', keep=False)]
          router        mac_address                 date
589455  15001391  00:00:34:1a:03:e8  2021-01-01 22:09:34
590136  17091236  00:00:34:1a:03:e8  2021-01-01 22:11:04
635434  15001391  00:00:78:01:0d:11  2021-01-02 00:14:54
636479  17091211  00:00:78:01:0d:11  2021-01-02 00:16:17
949873  17091172  00:00:af:82:56:93  2021-01-02 11:26:39
950703  17091258  00:00:af:82:56:93  2021-01-02 11:30:59
109858  17091236  00:02:75:86:4e:34  2021-01-01 05:50:47
110281  17091211  00:02:75:86:4e:34  2021-01-01 05:50:54
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first output you can `.groupby` on mac_address and then keep "first", "last":

```py
x = (
    df.groupby("mac_address")
    .agg(["first", "last"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="level_1")
)

print(x.drop_duplicates(keep="first"))
```

Prints:

```
          mac_address    router                date
0   00:00:34:1a:03:e8  15001391 2021-01-01 22:09:34
1   00:00:34:1a:03:e8  17091236 2021-01-01 22:11:04
2   00:00:78:01:0d:11  15001391 2021-01-02 00:14:54
3   00:00:78:01:0d:11  17091211 2021-01-02 00:16:17
4   00:00:af:82:56:93  17091172 2021-01-02 11:26:39
5   00:00:af:82:56:93  17091258 2021-01-02 11:30:59
6   00:01:09:d2:09:e0  17091174 2021-01-01 23:34:32
8   00:01:d2:7c:4e:32  17091211 2021-01-01 14:27:58
10  00:02:75:86:4e:34  17091236 2021-01-01 05:50:47
11  00:02:75:86:4e:34  17091211 2021-01-01 05:50:54
```

For the second output, just drop all duplicates:

```py
print(x.drop_duplicates(keep=False))
```

Prints:

```
          mac_address    router                date
0   00:00:34:1a:03:e8  15001391 2021-01-01 22:09:34
1   00:00:34:1a:03:e8  17091236 2021-01-01 22:11:04
2   00:00:78:01:0d:11  15001391 2021-01-02 00:14:54
3   00:00:78:01:0d:11  17091211 2021-01-02 00:16:17
4   00:00:af:82:56:93  17091172 2021-01-02 11:26:39
5   00:00:af:82:56:93  17091258 2021-01-02 11:30:59
10  00:02:75:86:4e:34  17091236 2021-01-01 05:50:47
11  00:02:75:86:4e:34  17091211 2021-01-01 05:50:54
```